# lines joining corresponding vertices of similar triangles are concurrent

Tags: geometry

given two similar triangles, prove that the lines joining their corresponding vertices are concurrent.(their is an exception for the case when triangles are congruent or the case when two lines happen to be parallel. I have also wondered over the case when the triangle is flipped over and transformed homothetically however I got no clue.

please also explain if the problem itself is wrong!

Comment: The triangles need to be in homothetic position. As a counterexample to your claim consider the two triangles $\bigl((0,1),(0,0),(2,0)\bigr)$ and $\bigl((0,0),(2,0),(2,4)\bigr)$.

Comment: I agree with @Christian Blatter, the invoked property is in general FALSE. The question should be removed

Comment: ok but please explain if the triangles are in homothetic position

Answer (score 0):

The claim is true if the two triangles are in homothetic position,  meaning that corresponding sides are parallel.

In this case we just have an instance of [Desargues' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues%27s_theorem): The three points of intersection of corresponding sides are lying on a line, namely the line at infinity. Therefore the three lines connecting corresponding vertices meet in a point.